# Best way to have threads communicate with each other

Tags: python, multithreading

I currently have a project where I will have multiple threads of 2 different functions running.

```
def first_func():
    while True:
        #do_something...
        #depending on "something" xy may be set to true

        if xy == True:
            #resume all threads for function second_func()

def second_func():
    #do something
    #do another thing
    #wait until first_func tells us to resume...
    #once first_func tells us to resume, we do more stuff..
```

Essentially I will have hundreds of threads running for `second_func`, they will do a few actions, then sit and do nothing. Once a certain condition is meant in a thread that is running `first_func`, all threads running for `second_func` will resume their actions. I am wondering the best way to do this?

My 2 thoughts have been for `second_func()` to constantly be checking if a global variable (`xy` in this case) is `True`, then resume, but that seems like it would take up alot of memory if I had hundreds of threads checking a variable's status every 0.1 seconds or so. The 2nd idea was to have `first_func` establish a local websocket server, have `second_func` threads to connect to it, then wait until `first_func` says the var is `True` over the connection, then resume.

I feel like there has to be a better method than the 2 ideas I had above. Any ideas? First func should be able to "alert" all second func threads within a matter of a couple of milliseconds of `xy` becoming `True`.

Comment: It doesn't take any memory to check a variable 10x a second.  It does use CPU, but a small amount.  However, it seems like the `threading.Event` objects are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Does `second_func` loop?  That is, will `xy` be false, then true, then false, then true, etc.?

Comment: FWIW (off-topic): no need to write `if xy == True:` because `if xy:` will suffice.

Comment: It not a good idea to use busy-waiting loops that constantly check the status of something. Instead, with something like `threading.event()`, you can used its `wait()` method in one thread to block until some other thread sets its internal flag (or the waiting times-out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard python [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) object works well here:

```
go_flag = threading.Event()

def coordinator():
  do_some_work()
  go_flag.set()   # <- allow workers to proceed

def worker():
  do_some_work()
  do_more_work()
  
  go_flag.wait()  # <- wait for coordinator to say "ok"
  
  do_even_more_work()
```